# Scrolling issue in uitableview having textfields

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll, uitextfield

I have a`UItableview` with multiple sections and each has two rows containing the **label and the textfield**. While scrolling the data, the textfield changes its position.

[1]: [UITableView scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482289/uitableview-scrolling-issue)  This question has the similar problem as mine but i couldn't get the exact solution.

This is my data source i.e cellForAtIndexPath method.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UILabel *   mainLabel;    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];        
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 8.0, 100.0, 30.0)] autorelease];
    mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
    mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
    mainTF = [[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 8.0, 140.0, 30)] autorelease];
    mainTF.tag = MAINTEXTFIELD_TAG;
    mainTF.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    mainTF.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    mainTF.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mainTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    mainTF.delegate = self;
    mainTF.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    mainTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    mainTF.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    mainTF.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    mainTF.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainTF];
}
else{
    mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG];
    mainTF = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINTEXTFIELD_TAG];
}

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    mainLabel.text = @"Quantity";
    //mainTF.text =@"1";
}
else{
    mainLabel.text = @"Unit";
    //mainTF.text = @"100 grams";
}

// Configure the cell...
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dequeue your cells they will contain the data that was previously put inside. you should initiate the textfield.text to @"" each time you load a cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this. I couldn't get you ?

Comment: if you : UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; if it return a cell, this cell will already contain all the data that was put inside when it was first used

Comment: I'm very new to the programing. So please tell what's wrong with that line of code. and what i supposed to do in this code.

Comment: you should simply uncomment mainTF.text and set it to mainTF.text = @""

Comment: I set mainTF.text = @"" but this time when i scroll the tableview, the data inside the textfield disappears.

Comment: isn't it what you wanted? not having unwanted text showing in the textfield?

Comment: Yes this i want. my problem is that while scrolling the data inside the text field changes the position from first textfield to bottom textfield.did u get me now ?

Comment: I assume you have only one textfield per row. thus you should each time, set the text value of your text field. if its nothing put @"" if it should be something else, put something else. if you dont assign a value to your text field it will keep the one was set to it previously. if you dont want those trouble and you dont have many cells, dont dequeueresuable cell and put nil to the reuseidentifier

Comment: Actually i have 5 sections and each section has two rows,each row containing a label and the textfield and when we put the value in the textfield manually and scroll the tableview then data is getting lost while scrolling.I think here scrolling create the problem for the data to disappaer.Please help

Comment: yes i understand, if you want to keep the data you need to create 5x2 = 10 different textfields. you can do this in a loop and addd your textfields to an array and refer to your textfield using their index in the array and simply add them as a subview of your cell. thus [cell.contentView addsubView:[arrayOfTextFields objectAtIndex:index]]; or you keep doing what you did and in the textfield delegate you store the string in an array and you realocate the corresponding string to the cell textfield. In any case i'm not sure  you have a good implementation, maybe you shoud rethink your cells.

Comment: Any way Thanks for your useful thoughts. I'll follow your steps.